# How to extract attachment using Mime4j 0.7.2

Tags: attachment, james, mime4j

Can anybody help in pointing me to some code to extract attachments from Multipart Mime using Mime4j?  I couldn't find any, I need it for Mime4j 0.7.2(latest).  I am trying to process attachments from James Hook/Mailets.

Comment: Did you check the mime4j documentation? Are you saying a simple web search did not turn up anything? What code do you have so far? What exactly is not working?

Comment: Yes, I searched,  but couldn't anything fruitful.  Here is a paste of my code (mostly from james mime4j).  I want to extract the body and attachments (I don't want to write my own parser as there are all sorts of emails that can mess up my parser).  http://pastebin.com/w3YvBydp

Comment: Anybody can help here?  I don't know how to extract the attachment precisely, from this:            List<MIMEPart> parts = mm.getAttachments();

Answer (score -1):

Ok, found the answer, just have to loop parts.get(i).readOnce() or read().